New York 2025 Mayoral election. Any primaries?
I would like to understand the New York 2025 Mayoral election. On the Wikipedia entry are several "Democratic primary candidates". Will there be a primary election like there is to presidential elections so there only is one left before the real election?

The primary in the 2001 election was called off shortly after it began and rescheduled two weeks later because hijackers flew two airliners into the World Trade Center.  I don't know when or why they moved the primary from September to June.

It seems to have happened in the previous election, the first to use ranked-choice voting, so the change in the schedule probably had something to do with that.

Yes, as stated  in the New York Times: "Mr. Adams is running for a second term in a competitive Democratic primary next June". The winner of the primary will be the only Democratic candidate in the general election.
The article linked in the question also links to the Wikipedia article about the last primary which was in 2021. Adams got just over 30% in the first round and a slight majority in the second round.
